# How to include an MVC Razor variable within Url.Content?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

Using MVC 3 Razor, how can I specify a variable within a call to `@Url.Content()`.

Example:

```
@{
var myVar = Request.QueryString["foo"];
}

<a href="@Url.Content("~/bar?@myvar")">click here</a>
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You're already in the c# context at that point, so you can use the variable just like you would in a code file.  Try this:

```
<a href="@Url.Content("~/bar?" + myvar)">click here</a>
```

Comment: With all the magic we get in Mvc/Razor, I was hoping that there would be a syntax that doesn't involve a concatenator. Thanks, Kyle.

Comment: @Jed - use `string.Format`. Or better yet, create a `UrlHelper` extension that accepts the variable in the method and bubbles up to `Url.Content.` But looking at your example, perhaps `Html.ActionLink` is a better option, then you can pass in the variable as route params.

Answer (score 0):

Building up on RPM1984 comment, you could also do:

```
<a href="@Url.Content(string.Format("~/bar?{0}",myvar))">click here</a>
```