# Image not displayed in ASP.NET MVC view

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Is there any syntax issue in the following? I have seen the value of `@item.FileName` - it is the same as the name of the image in the images folder. When I tried to hard code it, it works fine.

Is there any syntax error? The image is in `image` folder of the solution.

**Code from View**

```
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        var x = @item.FileName; //Here i am checking to see the filename .It is returning  the right value.
        <img src= " @Url.Content("~/Content/themes/base/images/@item.FileName") " /> 
    }
```

**Controller Action Method**

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        SelectionModel sel = new SelectionModel();
        List<SelectionModel> lissel = new List<SelectionModel>();
        byte[] imagedata;

        string sql = "select filename from filestore";

        OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection(ConStr);
        OracleCommand com = new OracleCommand(sql, con);

        try
        {
            con.Open(); //Opening a connection

            OracleDataReader dr;
            dr = com.ExecuteReader();

            while (dr.Read())
            {
                sel.FileName = dr[0].ToString(); //Here i am getting filename from the database
                lissel.Add(sel);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {}

        return View(lissel);
    }
```

Comment: Maybe you need to reformat the ```@Url.Content()``` method a bit to somethin like: ```" @Url.Content("~/Content/themes/base/images/" + item.FileName) "``` See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6066002/how-to-include-an-mvc-razor-variable-within-url-content#answer-6066011

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that `@item.FileName` is a string. In that case you'd need to do some concatenation:

```
<img src= " @Url.Content("~/Content/themes/base/images/" + @item.FileName + "\") "/>
```

Comment: Hello Quinn.Thanks .your idea of concatination was fine but

Comment: <img src= " @Url.Content("~/Content/themes/base/images/" + item.FileName ") "/>